# Why compiler is complaining Construction of sorted collection with non-comparable elements when the Data is implemented Comparator interface?

Tags: java, android, collections

I want to create list of sorted items so I decided to use TreeSet
Here is my code. and it is complaining `Construction of sorted collection with non-comparable elements` Wondering why the compiler is complaining and then you can see Info class is implementing Comparator but it is still complaining I understand it is expecting as constructor , but I don't understand why?

```
TreeSet<Info> items = new TreeSet<>()
```

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Info implements Comparator<Info> {

  public abstract long millisecond();


  public abstract String uri();


  public static Info create(
          long millisecond,  String uri) {
      return new AutoValue_Info(millisecond, uri);
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(Info t1, Info t2) {
      return ....;
  }
}
```

Comment: You must implement `Comparable`, not `Comparator` for this to work. But I belive you can also pass a comparator into the constructor of the `TreeSet` if you don't want to implement Comparable.

Comment: Thanks and I am wondering why it is not considering it natural ordering and requiring to implement Comparable ?

Comment: The error says it all: "with non-**comparable** elements".

Comment: And Please add your comment as answer I will vote

Comment: @I.S Because implementing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) *is* the definition of "natural ordering", so says the javadoc: *This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's **natural ordering**, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its **natural comparison method**.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must implement `Comparable`, not `Comparator` for this to work.

Java has two common options to make objects comparable. If the object can be modified implementing the `Comparable` interface works in most standard library classes. For objects that cannot / should not be modified a `Comparator` can be created. The comparator object is then passed in as additional information, e.g. for the `TreeSet` there is a constructor that takes the comparator object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in a comparator if you don't want to explicitly implement `Comparable`.

```java
Map<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass> someMap =
        new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(SomeClass::someInstanceMethod));
```